# A coin is tossed until the same result appears twice in a row

Tags: probability

> A coin is tossed until the same result appears twice in a row. Find the probability that the coin is tossed
>
> (a) less than 6 times.
>
> (b) an even number of times.

what i did :

(a)$= 1-p(\text{same result doesn't appears in 6 tosses})=1-(1/2)^5$

(b)= let P be the probability to get same result as # 2k-1 toss in the #2k toss

$p=0.5+0.5*0.5p \implies p=2/3$

is it correct?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format your questions correctly : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

I *almost* agree with both of your answers.
The key observation is that the event "matches the previous toss"
cannot happen on toss $1$ but happens with probability $\frac12$
on each later toss.
The complementary event "doesn't match the previous toss"
always happens on toss $1$ and happens with probability $\frac12$
on each later toss.

The flaw in part (a) is that you've given the probability that the coin
is tossed less than $7$ times ($6$ times or fewer).
"Less than $6$ tosses" is false if toss $2$, toss $3$, toss $4$, and
toss $5$ all fail to match; otherwise "less than $6$ tosses" is true.
That's just four tosses that have to fail to match, not five.

Part (b) could use a little more explanation.
I think what you're doing is taking the $\frac12$ chance that
a match first occurs on toss $2$, and then considering the case
where a match occurs neither on toss $2$ nor on toss $3$.
That case occurs with probability $\frac12 \cdot \frac12$,
and when it does occur, the probability of a match on an even toss
(on toss $4$ or later) is the same as the probability
of a match on an even toss (toss $2$ or later) at the start of the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your (b).

Let's consider the random variable $X$ giving the rank of the first apparition of a repetition. $X$ takes values in $\mathbb N\setminus\left\{0,1\right\}$.

Saying that $X=k$ means that there is no repetition in the first $k-1$ tosses, and the $(k-1)$th and $k$th tosses give the same result. So, to generalize a bit and use an *a priori* not fair coin, say $\mathbb P(\text{tail})=p$ :
$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\cases{(pq)^{\frac{k-2}{2}p^2} 
  + (qp)^{\frac{k-2}{2}q^2} & \text{ if $k$ is even} \\ 
  (pq)^{\frac{k-1}{2}q} + (qp)^{\frac{k-1}{2}p} & \text{ 
  if $k$ is odd}}$$
To simplify :
$$\mathbb P(X=2i)=(pq)^{i-1}(p^2+q^2) \qquad \text{and}\qquad 
  \mathbb P(X=2i+1)=(pq)^i$$
It doesn't give a pretty answer for question (a) :
$$\mathbb P(X\le 6) = (p^2+q^2)(pq+p^2q^2+p^3q^3)+pq+p^2q^2$$
which gives $\mathbb P(X\le 6) = \frac{61}{128}$ for a fair coin.

For the second question, the result is
$$\mathbb P(X\text{ even}) = \sum_{i=2}^\infty (pq)^{i-1}(p^2+q^2)
  = (pq)(p^2+q^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (pq)^n = \frac{(pq)(p^2+q^2)}{1-pq}$$
and this gives $\mathbb P(X\text{ even}) = \frac{1}{6}$ for a fair coin.

Hope I didn't say something wrong in my reasoning...