# Using Bernulli trial to find the probability the same result appears twice in a row when tossing a coin

Tags: probability

> A coin is tossed until the same result appears twice in a row. Find
> the probability that the coin is tossed less than 6 times.

I have to solve it using [Bernulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) but I cannot get the answer right.

$P(k)=\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ k\end{array}\right) p^k q^{n-k}$

It didn't help reading the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000613/a-coin-is-tossed-until-the-same-result-appears-twice-in-a-row) asked earlier. Answers differ slightly

The right answer is  $\frac{15}{16}$, according to this [website](https://tvims.nsu.ru/chernova/tv/solution/node6.html#SECTION6) where it is the 6.2.a excercise

I considered $n=6, k = 2, p= 0,5.$ Computing those values I don't get the desired answer

Comment: You're calculating the probability of exactly 2 heads occurring in 6 flips.  That's not the question; twice *in a row* is pretty important here.

Comment: @mjqxxxx How do I express that using the Bernulli trial

Comment: I think you don't :).

Comment: The only way six flips would be required is if you toss THTHT or HTHTH with the first five.  Each of those cases has probability $1/32$.

Comment: *Bernoulli* has an **o**